# Compile four a6 pages on one a4

Tags: pgfpages

I'm new to Latex and I'm trying to copy my first page on every page. I would like to have my a6paper document, repeated 4 times on a4 paper. I don't want to use the includepdf solution that I already know. I found something interesting here ([Compile two A5 pages on one A4 page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142187/compile-two-a5-pages-on-one-a4-page)), but I'm not able to duplicate 4 times.

I've tried another solution using pgf, but it doesn't work too.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a6paper,landscape,french]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{
4 on 1
}
{%\def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
}
{
\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions{%
logical pages=4,%
current logical shipout=1} 
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{copy from=1}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{copy from=1}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{copy from=1}
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a sub-optimal solution, but something that works: using the `atbegshi` package, I was able to copy the `AtBeginShipoutBox` in the other pages, thus making your layout effective. It takes effect only from page 2 (physical) though

```
\documentclass[11pt,a6paper,landscape,french]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape]

%\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{copy from=1}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{copy from=1}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{copy from=1}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{copy from=1}


\AtBeginShipout{%
\pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage{1}\copy\AtBeginShipoutBox
   \pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage{2}\vbox{\AtBeginShipoutBox}
    \pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage{3}\vbox{\AtBeginShipoutBox}
    \pgfpagesshipoutlogicalpage{4}\vbox{\AtBeginShipoutBox}
    \pgfshipoutphysicalpage
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]